# Clipping MBTiles Dataset using QGIS

Tags: qgis, clip, mbtiles

I have got a large MBTiles Raster Dataset with several Zoom Levels, about 40 GB.
Is it possible to clip a small area out of this large file e.g. 1 square kilometer which covers my area of interest?

Everything I am trying is crashing my QGIS.

Answer (score 0):

QGIS has not been optimized to manage a 40 GB MbTiles filtering.

You should better adopt `tilelive-copy` command line approach. It's done to create an extract from MBTtiles input. You can filter MBTiles by bounds, zoom or both. Look at [OpenMapTiles "Create custom Extract" doc](https://openmaptiles.org/docs/generate/create-custom-extract/)

I admit it's less convenient as you will need to install/use Node.js

Comment: Thank you for your info! Is there any other way to do it without experience in such command tools or a stey by step practice?

Comment: Do not know more. Sorry. You need to wait for other answer(s). The provided link gives you a step by step. Maybe, there are not enough details I suppose as you do not have command line experience. What is your OS? Windows, Mac, Linux?